# How many labeled trees with $n$ vertices? Answer: $n!(n-1)!$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

My proof:

Lemma: During the construction of a tree, except with the first vertex, there comes a exactly another new vertex with each new edge added.

Proof of lemma:if not, let's suppose it occurs when adding the k'th edge, we do not add another new vertex.therefore two of the previous vertices are now directly connected by this new edge, let's call them A,B. assuming what we have constructed up to now is a tree, it means that there was a exactly one path between A and B, and now there is another direct route, leading to a contradiction.

Proof of result:Let us start constructing our tree, to choose our starting point $A_{1}$ we have $n$ choices,and to chose the next vertex $A_{2}$ we've got $n-1$ choices, which we will directly connect to $A_{1}$. for the next one, we have $n-2$ choices, but we also have to decide if we want to connect it to $A_{1} $ or $A_{2}$,giving us 2 choices here as well, following this procedure and using the rule of product we get:

$$n!(n-1)!$$

NOTE:I know there are some problems with this proof, although I haven't been able to think about  them clearly.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula) would be useful.

Comment: @Rohan, Thank you, I would really apprecaite it if some of my wrong assumptions in my proof were pointed out. I seem to be blind to them

Comment: Follow your procedure for small numbers like $n=3$ and see what goes wrong. I have the strong impression that trees are counted more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what is wrong with your proof. For $n=2$, there are two ways to do your procedure. Suppose the two vertices are $A$ and $B$.

- Choose $A$ to be the start vertex, then connect $B$ to $A$.
- Choose $B$ to be the start vertex, then connect $A$ to $B$.

The problem is that these lead to the same tree, `A --- B`. This tree has been overcounted.

In general, there are many ways to build the same tree by choosing a start point and choosing an order to connect the other vertices to the growing tree. You are over-counting by a lot. Unfortunately, the number of ways to build each tree using your procedure is different from tree to tree, so this cannot be fixed by a simple division.

Answer (score 1):

This already goes wrong when $n=2$: $n!(n-1)! = 2$, but there's only one labelled tree on two vertices.

The result you should get is [$n^{n-2}$](//oeis.org/A000272). There's a lot of references on OEIS.

The easiest way to get there might be via the number of *rooted* labelled trees: [$n^{n-1}$](//oeis.org/A000169). (Hint: direct the edges).

The factor of $n$ difference between the two is very easy to explain...